# Can "in between" refer to a single continuous action?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, prepositions

Can we say *in between* if we are in the middle of an action? For example:

> The doctor told me not to eat anything after midnight. In the morning I accidentally ate a seed and recalled as I was in between [eating].

Comment: You could say _...and recalled as I was chewing_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP's usage would *always* be wrong. In a time-based context, you can only be "in between" *two different things*. As Jeremy says, you can be *in between jobs/relationships*, because this places you between the *previous* job/relationship, and the (possibly hypothetical) *future* one.

For a single instance of an activity that lasts long enough to speak of some particular moment while it's still ongoing, you can say you're **in the middle of** [eating].

As an aside, *recall* is more often used for making a specific effort to recollect some past memory or knowledge. In OP's context, *remembered* or perhaps *realised* would be more likely.

Comment: Thanks. How about these two: "I remembered as I was in the middle of eating and had to spit it out" Or : "I remembered as I was in the middle of eating and had to throw it out"

Comment: @Noah: Yes - that would be a perfectly natural way of putting it. For just "a seed" (a bit unlikely anyway) I suppose it would *all* be in your mouth, so you'd say *"spit it out"*. For something bigger that you wouldn't keep for later (like fried egg on toast), you'd more likely *"throw it out"*. Also, it would be quite common to shorten the construction to just *"I remembered in the middle of eating, and had to throw it out"*.

Comment: Does the 'throw it out' part implies throwing it out from the mouth or trashing it? The spitting seems to be clear as it's spitting out from the mouth.

Comment: @Noah: You don't *throw* things out of your mouth, because throwing is an action done with your hands and arms, not mouth and tongue. If you *throw [something edible] out*, it normally means you put in in the wastebin (using hands/arms).

Comment: I see. But we can say that I threw up my breakfast, right(which I think means vomiting)? Is there any other word for throwing out things using tongue and mouth besides spitting?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't say that. For example, you might say you are "in between jobs" or "in between relationships", but you wouldn't say you're "in between working" or "in between dating". Even then, this isn't a terribly common phrase, but you would use it with nouns.

Also, your last sentence doesn't really work. Is it just part of a sentence? Or do you need to move some words around? Maybe you just meant "I recoiled" rather than "I recalled".

A better way to put it would be:

*In the morning I ate a seed before remembering that I was meant to be fasting.*

Fasting means "refusing to eat for some period of time."

or

*In the morning I ate a seed even though I wasn't supposed to eat anything.*

Comment: "In between meals" is perfectly fine, but "in between eating" sounds funny.

Comment: @PeterShor "In between meals" doesn't imply this state of purposefully trying not to eat, though.

Comment: @PeterShor- I know mine one does seem funny. But Google Books seem to be spitting out a lot of results, using it a little differently:1.) *In between eating, I keep yawning* 2.) *In between eating they exchanged remarks with the proprietor of the Paris Hotel*